# How to enable middle mouse click scroll on all apps

Tags: mouse

I am trying to enable middle mouse click scroll (see screenshot) on all apps, currently it only works on Firefox. It is not magic mouse.

Please help me.

I am using currently my first not Magic Mouse, and scrolling is slow, and only way to go quick is to use the "click middle button" and when the two arrows appear, go up or down. I want to replicate this on all apps, not just FF.

[image]

Comment: What kind of mouse are you using? How did you configure it for Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Firefox-specific behaviour, not Mac behaviour. It's called Autoscrolling, in FF prefs.

> [image]

You can chenge the speed of the Mac's scroll wheel in System Settings > Accessibility > Pointer Settings

[image]